# Format list in email

Tags: python, string, list, python-2.6

I have script, which collect some data:

```
...
REPORT = []
...
if re.search('^-', line):
    logging.info('File %s in line %d: %s' % (file, num, line))
    REPORT.append('File %s in line %d: %s' % (file, num, line))
...
```

And then send email:

```
body = email.mime.Text.MIMEText("""

Report:

%s

""" % REPORT)

msg.attach(body)
```

But it's arrives in 'raw' view, like:

> Report:
>
> ```
> ['File services.PROD.properties in line 29: - \r\n', 'File services.PROD.properties in line 30: - Url=https://someurl.com/reporting\r\n', 'File services.properties in line 44: - gUrl=http://someurl.com:11704/uu.dll\r\n', ']
> ```

How can I format it to send usual lines/strings?

**Python** 2.6

Comment: What does `REPORT` look like after the `for`-loop on top? Can you post that, or, alternatively, the content of `line`?

Comment: @jkalden edited with report example output

Comment: ok, tested. I go with the answer given by @falsetru

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to join strings with newline:

```
>>> '\n'.join(['line1', 'line2', 'line3'])
'line1\nline2\nline3'
>>> print('\n'.join(['line1', 'line2', 'line3']))
line1
line2
line3
```

---

```
body = email.mime.Text.MIMEText("""

Report:

%s

""" % '\n'.join(REPORT))
```

Comment: @setevoy, Your edited list contains carriage return and newline; you can use `''.join(REPORT)` instead if you don't want additional newline.